# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException in if statem

Tags: java, multithreading

```
if (charIte.next()=='{' || charIte.next()=='}'
                || charIte.next()=='[' || charIte.next()==']' 
                || charIte.next()=='(' || charIte.next()==')'
                || charIte.next()=='*' || charIte.next()=='"' 
                || charIte.next()=='/'){
}
```

The program returns:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException at line
|| charIte.next()=='(' || charIte.next()==')'
```

What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is you're calling `next()` too many times. You need to store it in a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Each invocation of `next()` consumes **one token**. Call it once, and save and then compare with the result. Like,

```
char ch = charIte.next();
if (ch == '{' || ch == '}' || ch == '[' || ch == ']' || ch == '(' 
            || ch == ')' || ch == '*' || ch == '"' || ch == '/') {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time you do charIte.next() you're asking to read the next token.
I think what you should do to is`char ite = charIte.next.chartAt(0)` and then use ite in your if statement

```
if (ite next()=='{' || next()=='}' 
|| ite.next()=='[' || ite.next()==']' 
            || ite.next()=='(' || ite.next()==')'
            || ite.next()=='*' || ite.next()=='"' 
            || ite.next()=='/'){
```

[Info on Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)